# How to release a block

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, objective-c-blocks

I am storing my blocks while my web service goes off and talks to my server. Therefore I am using `[myBlock copy]` to keep a reference to my block.

Once I have got my data, and executed the block, do I call `[myBlock release]`, or do I use `Block_release(myBlock)` ? I can find reference to both.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Block_release()` is there for when you're only using blocks in C, and not Objective-C.

When using Objective-C you can use the `release` and `copy` methods to make your code look and feel more like the rest of the ObjC around it.

I imagine they both do exactly the same thing, and that the objc method is just a wrapper around the call to `Block_release()` anyway.

Answer (score 5):

As [it's explained in reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH5-SW6) The sum of copy/release must be equal zero. So if you are using Objective-C you can call `[block copy]` and therefore `[block release]`.

If you are using C, you shall use `Block_copy()` and `Block_release()`.

As Jasarien wrote they are probably doing the same thing, so you can use them interchangeably. However it is important to keep the convention consistent- so when you use `[block copy]` you'd rather use `[block release]` than `Block_release()`